# Check if URL exists in R

Tags: r, url, rcurl, httr

I want to loop over a list of URLs and I want to find out if these URLs exist or not.

`RCurl` provides the `url.exists()` function. However, the output doesn't seem to be right, because for example it says that amazon.com is not registered (it does so because the `url.exists()`-function doesn't return a value in the 200 range, in the case of amazon.com it's 405 ("method not allowed").

I also tried `HEAD()` and `GET()` provided by the `httr` package. But sometimes I get error messages here, for example for timeouts or because the URL is not registered.

Error messages look like this:

`Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  Timeout was reached: Connection timed out after 10000 milliseconds`

`Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  Could not resolve host: afsadadssadasf.com`

When I get such an error, the whole for loop stops. Is it possible to continue the for loop? I tried `tryCatch()`, but to my knowledge this can only help when the problem is in the dataframe itself.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`pingr::ping()` only uses ICMP which is blocked on sane organizational networks since attackers used ICMP as a way to exfiltrate data and communicate with command-and-control servers.

`pingr::ping_port()` doesn't use the HTTP `Host:` header so the IP address may be responding but the target virtual web host may not be running on it and it definitely doesn't validate that the path exists at the target URL.

You should clarify what you want to happen when there are only non-200:299 range HTTP status codes. The following makes an assumption.

NOTE: You used Amazon as an example and I'm *hoping* that's the first site that just "came to mind" since it's unethical and a crime to scrape Amazon and I would appreciate my code not being brought into your universe if you are in fact just a brazen content thief. If you are stealing content, it's unlikely you'd be up front here about that, but on the outside chance you are both stealing and have a conscience, please let me know so I can delete this answer so at least other content thieves can't use it.

Here's a self-contained function for checking URLs:

```
#' @param x a single URL
#' @param non_2xx_return_value what to do if the site exists but the
#'        HTTP status code is not in the `2xx` range. Default is to return `FALSE`.
#' @param quiet if not `FALSE`, then every time the `non_2xx_return_value` condition
#'        arises a warning message will be displayed. Default is `FALSE`.
#' @param ... other params (`timeout()` would be a good one) passed directly
#'        to `httr::HEAD()` and/or `httr::GET()`
url_exists <- function(x, non_2xx_return_value = FALSE, quiet = FALSE,...) {

  suppressPackageStartupMessages({
    require("httr", quietly = FALSE, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
  })

  # you don't need thse two functions if you're alread using `purrr`
  # but `purrr` is a heavyweight compiled pacakge that introduces
  # many other "tidyverse" dependencies and this doesnt.

  capture_error <- function(code, otherwise = NULL, quiet = TRUE) {
    tryCatch(
      list(result = code, error = NULL),
      error = function(e) {
        if (!quiet)
          message("Error: ", e$message)

        list(result = otherwise, error = e)
      },
      interrupt = function(e) {
        stop("Terminated by user", call. = FALSE)
      }
    )
  }

  safely <- function(.f, otherwise = NULL, quiet = TRUE) {
    function(...) capture_error(.f(...), otherwise, quiet)
  }

  sHEAD <- safely(httr::HEAD)
  sGET <- safely(httr::GET)

  # Try HEAD first since it's lightweight
  res <- sHEAD(x, ...)

  if (is.null(res$result) || 
      ((httr::status_code(res$result) %/% 200) != 1)) {

    res <- sGET(x, ...)

    if (is.null(res$result)) return(NA) # or whatever you want to return on "hard" errors

    if (((httr::status_code(res$result) %/% 200) != 1)) {
      if (!quiet) warning(sprintf("Requests for [%s] responded but without an HTTP status code in the 200-299 range", x))
      return(non_2xx_return_value)
    }

    return(TRUE)

  } else {
    return(TRUE)
  }

}
```

Give it a go:

```
c(
  "http://content.thief/",
  "http://rud.is/this/path/does/not_exist",
  "https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=content+theft", 
  "https://www.google.com/search?num=100&source=hp&ei=xGzMW5TZK6G8ggegv5_QAw&q=don%27t+be+a+content+thief&btnK=Google+Search&oq=don%27t+be+a+content+thief&gs_l=psy-ab.3...934.6243..7114...2.0..0.134.2747.26j6....2..0....1..gws-wiz.....0..0j35i39j0i131j0i20i264j0i131i20i264j0i22i30j0i22i10i30j33i22i29i30j33i160.mY7wCTYy-v0", 
  "https://rud.is/b/2018/10/10/geojson-version-of-cbc-quebec-ridings-hex-cartograms-with-example-usage-in-r/"
) -> some_urls

data.frame(
  exists = sapply(some_urls, url_exists, USE.NAMES = FALSE),
  some_urls,
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
) %>% dplyr::tbl_df() %>% print()
##  A tibble: 5 x 2
##   exists some_urls                                                                           
##   <lgl>  <chr>                                                                               
## 1 NA     http://content.thief/                                                               
## 2 FALSE  http://rud.is/this/path/does/not_exist                                              
## 3 TRUE   https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=con…
## 4 TRUE   https://www.google.com/search?num=100&source=hp&ei=xGzMW5TZK6G8ggegv5_QAw&q=don%27t…
## 5 TRUE   https://rud.is/b/2018/10/10/geojson-version-of-cbc-quebec-ridings-hex-cartograms-wi…
## Warning message:
## In FUN(X[[i]], ...) :
##   Requests for [http://rud.is/this/path/does/not_exist] responded but without an HTTP status code in the 200-299 range
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanation. I'm not a content thief and actually I didn't come up with amazon.com first. Another user just used amazon.com to demonstrate the ping()-function. I do this just for a little university project and scraping is not my intetion. However, your provided code helps a lot for me as a beginner in R! Unfortunately, I still get an error when a URL does not exist: `Error in UseMethod("status_code") : no applicable method for 'status_code' applied to an object of class "NULL"` For some reason, the code still breaks before the if (is.null(res)) statement

Comment: Errant logical operator fixed and additional functionality added despite the questionable scraping claims.

Comment: I'm sorry, of course you are right. I have mentioned it at first. Sorry, it was late at night and today I just looked at the `formatted` text to find an amazon url in my initial post. It's 100% my bad. If I were a content thief who would like to scrape amazon, I probably wouldn't point to that particular website.
However, thank you again for your support, even though you see a potential content thief in me.

Answer (score 13):

Here is a simple solution to the problem.

```
urls <-   c("http://www.amazon.com",
            "http://this.isafakelink.biz",
            "https://stackoverflow.com")

valid_url <- function(url_in,t=2){
  con <- url(url_in)
  check <- suppressWarnings(try(open.connection(con,open="rt",timeout=t),silent=T)[1])
  suppressWarnings(try(close.connection(con),silent=T))
  ifelse(is.null(check),TRUE,FALSE)
}

sapply(urls,valid_url)
```

Comment: Use HEAD method might be a faster way to connect a site

Answer (score 4):

Try the `ping` function in the pingr package.  It gives the timings of pings.

```
library(pingr)

ping("amazon.com") # good site
## [1] 45 46 45

ping("xxxyyyzzz.com") # bad site
## [1] NA NA NA
```

Comment: Thanks, but using `ping()` I get only NAs for any site. Even for `ping("amazon.com")`. Following the pingr documentation, this one works fine: `ping_port("www.google.com", port = 80, count = 1)`. I will try again later with `ping()`

Comment: ICMP is likely (rightfully so) blocked on your network.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a function that evaluates an expression and returns `TRUE` if it works and `FALSE` if it doesn't. You can also assign variables inside the expression.

```
try_catch <- function(exprs) {!inherits(try(eval(exprs)), "try-error")}

try_catch(out <- log("a")) # returns FALSE
out # Error: object 'out' not found

try_catch(out <- log(1)) # returns TRUE
out # out = 0
```

You can use the expression to check for success.

```
done <- try_catch({
    # try something
})
if(!done) {
    done <- try_catch({
        # try something else
    })
}
if(!done) {
    # default expression
}
```